# PHP Read xlsx Excel 2007 file

Tags: php, file, xlsx

I am using oleread to read uploaded xls file. But I am not able to read xlsx files saved in excel-2007 format. can someone help me on how to read xlsx file in PHP.

Comment: Why isn't any answer accepted?

Answer (score 70):

```
<?php
require_once 'SimpleXLSX.php';

if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('pricelist.xlsx') ) {
  print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
} else {
  echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
?>
```

[SimpleXLSX](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx)

Comment: this class is far away slower than PHPExcel class which can read more formats than this one.

Comment: SimpleXLSX did the job, and so simple!, that's all I needed (+1).

Answer (score 22):

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) (see [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)) is probably your best option. It's very slick and easy to use, I've had no problem with the new XLSX format.

**Update :**

**PHPExcel - DEAD**

PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019.

The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), or another alternative.

Comment: (from an anonymous user): Just be aware that PHPExcel can be memory hungry. You should consider this if you will be using it with spreadsheets of a few megabytes or larger.

Comment: PHPExcel causes running out of memory when trying to load a 91kb .xlsx file... useless tool

Comment: The problem with PHPExcel is not only with heavy memory usage, but also with speed. On my test XLS file (0.5Mb) PHPExcel takes 5 times more memory than Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader (30Mb vs 6Mb) and 6 times slower (6 secs vs 1 sec) :(

Comment: I can also confirm that PHPExcel will use a huge load of resources in excel files with many rows and/or columns. Use it only for simple excel files.

Answer (score 3):

`XLSXReader` (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader)) is based on `SimpleXLSX` (see answer by Sergey Shuchkin).

Convert dates from xlsx using `XLSXReader::toUnixTimeStamp`.

**sample.xlsx**

[image: sample.xlsx]

**sample.php**

```
require (__DIR__ . '/../xlsxreader/XLSXReader.php');

// entire workbook
$xlsx = new XLSXReader('sample.xlsx');
$sheetNames = $xlsx->getSheetNames();

// loop through worksheets
foreach ($sheetNames as $sheetName) {
    $sheet = $xlsx->getSheet($sheetName);

    // worksheet header
    echo('<h3>' . htmlentities($sheetName) . '</h3><table>' . PHP_EOL);
    $xlsx_data = $sheet->getData();
    $header_row_xlsx = array_shift($xlsx_data);

    // header row
    echo('<tr>' . PHP_EOL);
    echo("\t<th>row</th>" . PHP_EOL);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header_row_xlsx); $i++) {
        $xlsx_field_name = '' . $header_row_xlsx[$i];
        echo("\t<th>" . htmlentities("$xlsx_field_name") . '</th>' . PHP_EOL);
    }
    echo('</tr>' . PHP_EOL);

    // loop through data rows
    $row_number = 1;
    foreach ($xlsx_data as $row_xlsx) {

        // data row
        echo('<tr>' . PHP_EOL);
        echo("\t<td>" . htmlentities("$row_number") . '</td>' . PHP_EOL);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($row_xlsx); $i++) {
            $xlsx_field_name = '' . ($i < count($header_row_xlsx) ? $header_row_xlsx[$i] : '');
            if ("$xlsx_field_name" === "DoB") {

                // date value
                $xlsx_field_value = DateTimeImmutable::
                        createFromFormat('U', XLSXReader::toUnixTimeStamp($row_xlsx[$i]))
                        ->format('Y-m-d');
            } else {

                // non-date value
                $xlsx_field_value = $row_xlsx[$i];

            }
            echo("\t<td>" . htmlentities("$xlsx_field_value") . '</td>' . PHP_EOL);
        }
        echo('</tr>' . PHP_EOL);

        $row_number++;
    }
    echo("</table><!-- end of $sheetName -->" . PHP_EOL);
}
```

**output**

```
<h3>Sheet1</h3><table>
<tr>
    <th>row</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>DoB</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1988-11-12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Walt</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>1972-01-19</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- end of Sheet1 -->
```

**XLSXReader.php**

```
<?php
/*
XLSXReader
Greg Neustaetter <gneustaetter@gmail.com>
Artistic License

XLSXReader is a heavily modified version of:
    SimpleXLSX php class v0.4 (Artistic License)
    Created by Sergey Schuchkin from http://www.sibvision.ru - professional php developers team 2010-2011
    Downloadable from GitHub.

Key Changes include:
    Separation into two classes - one for the Workbook and one for Worksheets
    Access to sheets by name or sheet id
    Use of ZIP extension
    On-demand access of files inside zip
    On-demand access to sheet data
    No storage of XML objects or XML text
    When parsing rows, include empty rows and null cells so that data array has same number of elements for each row
    Configuration option for removing trailing empty rows
    Better handling of cells with style information but no value
    Change of class names and method names
    Removed rowsEx functionality including extraction of hyperlinks
*/

class XLSXReader {
    protected $sheets = array();
    protected $sharedstrings = array();
    protected $sheetInfo;
    protected $zip;
    public $config = array(
        'removeTrailingRows' => true
    );

    // XML schemas
    const SCHEMA_OFFICEDOCUMENT  =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument';
    const SCHEMA_RELATIONSHIP  =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships';
    const SCHEMA_OFFICEDOCUMENT_RELATIONSHIP = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships';
    const SCHEMA_SHAREDSTRINGS =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings';
    const SCHEMA_WORKSHEETRELATION =  'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet';

    public function __construct($filePath, $config = array()) {
        $this->config = array_merge($this->config, $config);
        $this->zip = new ZipArchive();
        $status = $this->zip->open($filePath);
        if($status === true) {
            $this->parse();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Failed to open $filePath with zip error code: $status");
        }
    }

    // get a file from the zip
    protected function getEntryData($name) {
        $data = $this->zip->getFromName($name);
        if($data === false) {
            throw new Exception("File $name does not exist in the Excel file");
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    }

    // extract the shared string and the list of sheets
    protected function parse() {
        $sheets = array();
        $relationshipsXML = simplexml_load_string($this->getEntryData("_rels/.rels"));
        foreach($relationshipsXML->Relationship as $rel) {
            if($rel['Type'] == self::SCHEMA_OFFICEDOCUMENT) {
                $workbookDir = dirname($rel['Target']) . '/';
                $workbookXML = simplexml_load_string($this->getEntryData($rel['Target']));
                foreach($workbookXML->sheets->sheet as $sheet) {                
                    $r = $sheet->attributes('r', true);
                    $sheets[(string)$r->id] = array(
                        'sheetId' => (int)$sheet['sheetId'],
                        'name' => (string)$sheet['name']
                    );

                }
                $workbookRelationsXML = simplexml_load_string($this->getEntryData($workbookDir . '_rels/' . basename($rel['Target']) . '.rels'));
                foreach($workbookRelationsXML->Relationship as $wrel) {
                    switch($wrel['Type']) {
                        case self::SCHEMA_WORKSHEETRELATION:
                            $sheets[(string)$wrel['Id']]['path'] = $workbookDir . (string)$wrel['Target'];
                            break;
                        case self::SCHEMA_SHAREDSTRINGS:
                            $sharedStringsXML = simplexml_load_string($this->getEntryData($workbookDir . (string)$wrel['Target']));
                            foreach($sharedStringsXML->si as $val) {
                                if(isset($val->t)) {
                                    $this->sharedStrings[] = (string)$val->t;
                                } elseif(isset($val->r)) {
                                    $this->sharedStrings[] = XLSXWorksheet::parseRichText($val);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->sheetInfo = array();
        foreach($sheets as $rid=>$info) {
            $this->sheetInfo[$info['name']] = array(
                'sheetId' => $info['sheetId'],
                'rid' => $rid,
                'path' => $info['path']
            );
        }
    }

    // returns an array of sheet names, indexed by sheetId
    public function getSheetNames() {
        $res = array();
        foreach($this->sheetInfo as $sheetName=>$info) {
            $res[$info['sheetId']] = $sheetName;
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function getSheetCount() {
        return count($this->sheetInfo);
    }

    // instantiates a sheet object (if needed) and returns an array of its data
    public function getSheetData($sheetNameOrId) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetNameOrId);
        return $sheet->getData();
    }

    // instantiates a sheet object (if needed) and returns the sheet object
    public function getSheet($sheet) {
        if(is_numeric($sheet)) {
            $sheet = $this->getSheetNameById($sheet);
        } elseif(!is_string($sheet)) {
            throw new Exception("Sheet must be a string or a sheet Id");
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($sheet, $this->sheets)) {
            $this->sheets[$sheet] = new XLSXWorksheet($this->getSheetXML($sheet), $sheet, $this);

        }
        return $this->sheets[$sheet];
    }

    public function getSheetNameById($sheetId) {
        foreach($this->sheetInfo as $sheetName=>$sheetInfo) {
            if($sheetInfo['sheetId'] === $sheetId) {
                return $sheetName;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Sheet ID $sheetId does not exist in the Excel file");
    }

    protected function getSheetXML($name) {
        return simplexml_load_string($this->getEntryData($this->sheetInfo[$name]['path']));
    }

    // converts an Excel date field (a number) to a unix timestamp (granularity: seconds)
    public static function toUnixTimeStamp($excelDateTime) {
        if(!is_numeric($excelDateTime)) {
            return $excelDateTime;
        }
        $d = floor($excelDateTime); // seconds since 1900
        $t = $excelDateTime - $d;
        return ($d > 0) ? ( $d - 25569 ) * 86400 + $t * 86400 : $t * 86400;
    }

}

class XLSXWorksheet {

    protected $workbook;
    public $sheetName;
    protected $data;
    public $colCount;
    public $rowCount;
    protected $config;

    public function __construct($xml, $sheetName, XLSXReader $workbook) {
        $this->config = $workbook->config;
        $this->sheetName = $sheetName;
        $this->workbook = $workbook;
        $this->parse($xml);
    }

    // returns an array of the data from the sheet
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    protected function parse($xml) {
        $this->parseDimensions($xml->dimension);
        $this->parseData($xml->sheetData);
    }

    protected function parseDimensions($dimensions) {
        $range = (string) $dimensions['ref'];
        $cells = explode(':', $range);
        $maxValues = $this->getColumnIndex($cells[1]);
        $this->colCount = $maxValues[0] + 1;
        $this->rowCount = $maxValues[1] + 1;
    }

    protected function parseData($sheetData) {
        $rows = array();
        $curR = 0;
        $lastDataRow = -1;
        foreach ($sheetData->row as $row) {
            $rowNum = (int)$row['r'];
            if($rowNum != ($curR + 1)) {
                $missingRows = $rowNum - ($curR + 1);
                for($i=0; $i < $missingRows; $i++) {
                    $rows[$curR] = array_pad(array(),$this->colCount,null);
                    $curR++;
                }
            }
            $curC = 0;
            $rowData = array();
            foreach ($row->c as $c) {
                list($cellIndex,) = $this->getColumnIndex((string) $c['r']);
                if($cellIndex !== $curC) {
                    $missingCols = $cellIndex - $curC;
                    for($i=0;$i<$missingCols;$i++) {
                        $rowData[$curC] = null;
                        $curC++;
                    }
                }
                $val = $this->parseCellValue($c);
                if(!is_null($val)) {
                    $lastDataRow = $curR;
                }
                $rowData[$curC] = $val;
                $curC++;
            }
            $rows[$curR] = array_pad($rowData, $this->colCount, null);
            $curR++;
        }
        if($this->config['removeTrailingRows']) {
            $this->data = array_slice($rows, 0, $lastDataRow + 1);
            $this->rowCount = count($this->data);
        } else {
            $this->data = $rows;
        }
    }

    protected function getColumnIndex($cell = 'A1') {
        if (preg_match("/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/", $cell, $matches)) {

            $col = $matches[1];
            $row = $matches[2];
            $colLen = strlen($col);
            $index = 0;

            for ($i = $colLen-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                $index += (ord($col{$i}) - 64) * pow(26, $colLen-$i-1);
            }
            return array($index-1, $row-1);
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid cell index");
    }

    protected function parseCellValue($cell) {
        // $cell['t'] is the cell type
        switch ((string)$cell["t"]) {
            case "s": // Value is a shared string
                if ((string)$cell->v != '') {
                    $value = $this->workbook->sharedStrings[intval($cell->v)];
                } else {
                    $value = '';
                }
                break;
            case "b": // Value is boolean
                $value = (string)$cell->v;
                if ($value == '0') {
                    $value = false;
                } else if ($value == '1') {
                    $value = true;
                } else {
                    $value = (bool)$cell->v;
                }
                break;
            case "inlineStr": // Value is rich text inline
                $value = self::parseRichText($cell->is);
                break;
            case "e": // Value is an error message
                if ((string)$cell->v != '') {
                    $value = (string)$cell->v;
                } else {
                    $value = '';
                }
                break;
            default:
                if(!isset($cell->v)) {
                    return null;
                }
                $value = (string)$cell->v;

                // Check for numeric values
                if (is_numeric($value)) {
                    if ($value == (int)$value) $value = (int)$value;
                    elseif ($value == (float)$value) $value = (float)$value;
                    elseif ($value == (double)$value) $value = (double)$value;
                }
        }
        return $value;
    }

    // returns the text content from a rich text or inline string field
    public static function parseRichText($is = null) {
        $value = array();
        if (isset($is->t)) {
            $value[] = (string)$is->t;
        } else {
            foreach ($is->r as $run) {
                $value[] = (string)$run->t;
            }
        }
        return implode(' ', $value);
    }
}
```

While I recommend getting the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader), the entire 1-file library is less than 400 lines of code, so I included the current version (11/10/2018) above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with phpspreadsheet :

```
  include 'vendor/autoload.php';
        if($_FILES["import_excel"]["name"] != '')
        {
            $allowed_extension = array('xls', 'csv', 'xlsx');
            $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["import_excel"]["name"]);
            $file_extension = end($file_array);
            if(in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension))
            {
                $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['import_excel']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
                $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
                $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
                $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);
                unlink($file_name);
                $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
                foreach($data as $row)
                {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        ':test1'          =>  $row[0],
                        ':test2'          =>  $row[1],
                        ':test3'          =>  $row[2],
                        ':test4'          =>  $row[3]
                    );
                 };
                $query = "
                    INSERT INTO post
                    (  test1, test2, test3, test4)
                    VALUES
                    ( :test1, :test2, :test3, :test4)
                ";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute($insert_data);
             }
             echo "succes";
        }else{
           echo "only xls,csv,xlsx are allowed";
        }
```