# Import .xlsx data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel

I am working on importing `.xlsx` data to a MySQL database.
The data is uploading perfect if I choose a `.csv` file, but when I choose a `.xlsx` file it will insert dummy data. How do I solve this? Here is the screenshot :

[image]

and here is my code. Found from Google

reference : https://hemant9807.blogspot.in/2016/09/import-excelcsv-file-to-mysql-database.html

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    //First we need to make a connection with the database
    $host=''; // Host Name.
    $db_user= ''; //User Name
    $db_password= '';
    $db= ''; // Database Name.
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db) or die (mysqli_error());
    //mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM test";
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //print_r($emapData);
            //exit();
            $sql = "INSERT into test(image) values ('$emapData[0]')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        //header('Location: upload.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot expect to be able to read an xlsx file as if it were a CSV file. They are two entirely different formats.

Comment: You're using `fgetcsv` to read an xlsx file. This can't work. Note that the article you link talks about loading an "excel csv", not an xlsx file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Read xlsx Excel 2007 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528213/php-read-xlsx-excel-2007-file)

Comment: how to read xlsx file @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: You will first convert Excel to CSV file and then import it.  Here is some instructions for you (http://hayageek.com/convert-xls-to-csv-in-php/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link](http://hayageek.com/convert-xls-to-csv-in-php/) given by ian0411 is working. i did.nt test it.
 but i done in this way so this will work.

first i  convert my excel file csv and then i uploaded it to server it works fine.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is a plain text file, but an Excel file like xls or xlsx is not.  If you want to import directly from an Excel file you need to you a utility that can read the Excel file format.